# Adding two conditions to joinLeft in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

This compiles:

```
  val table1 = TableQuery[Table1]
  val table2 = TableQuery[Table2]

  val query = for {
    (t1, t2) <- table1 joinLeft table2 on (_.dsType === _.dsType)
  } yield (t1, t2)
```

This does *not* compile:

```
  val table1 = TableQuery[Table1]
  val table2 = TableQuery[Table2]

  val query = for {
    (t1, t2) <- table1 joinLeft table2 on (_.dsType === _.dsType && _.dsSk === _.dsSk)
  } yield (t1, t2)
```

What's the syntax to add two conditions to `joinLeft` ?

Comment: Four underscores in your anonymous function indicate it should take four arguments, and each nth argument corresponds to the nth underscore. But `on` wants a function that takes 2 arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify to which table you ask for the attributes within the on and separate by the operator &&:

```
  val table1 = TableQuery[Table1]
  val table2 = TableQuery[Table2]

    val query = for {
      (t1, t2) <- table1.joinLeft(table2).on((tab1, tab2) => tab1.dsType === tab2.dsType && tab1.dsSk === tab2.dsSk)
    } yield (t1, t2)
```

Similar to this question was answered in:
[How to add AND to the join SLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405246/how-to-add-and-to-the-join-slick)